# Endpoints are not generated when adding a Json Webservice in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, web-services

I am adding a Json webservice reference to my application. If I add a normal Soap webservice (via the add webreference option in VS2012) the endpoints are generated in the web.config, however they do not get generated when connecting to the Json service. Is this normal behaviour or do I need to connect to a Json webservice in a different manner? As it is errors are obviously thrown when trying to use the service in code.